# How to implement multiselect select2 inside tabulator cell

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, tabulator

I am using tabultor.js to load my data.I need implement jquery select2 multi select inside each cell for a particular column.Any working example with sample data welcome.Help me to solve this.

Below I have tried with **custom editor** but its not working Please have look and help me.

https://jsfiddle.net/harifrais/gyobsk53/3/

`test`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your example.

The first problem is that you are not importing the select2 library into JSFiddle. you can see this in the console where it says

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

There are two actual errors in your editor. The first is that you are trying to reference the element by ID, you should not do this in a virtualDOM environment, you should just pass the editor directly into the jQuery selector

```js
$(editor).select2({ //Pass the editor variable straight into the jQuery selector, no need for ID
    closeOnSelect: false,
    data:colorsToAccessSelect,
});
```

The second issue is that you are trying to instantiate the `select2` before the element has been added to the DOM, which will cause the library to fail.

You need to make sure that you instantiate it inside the ***onRendered*** callback, which is called when the editor has been added to the DOM and is visible.

```js
onRendered(function(){      
    $(editor).select2({
        closeOnSelect: false,
        data:colorsToAccessSelect,
    });
  
    editor.focus();
});
```

On a side note, Tabulator already comes with a built in [Select Editor](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/edit#edit-builtin). There is demo of it in action in the [Editor Example](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.7#editable) in the gender column

For example to setup multiselect on a column, in the definition you need to set the ***editor*** to "select" and setup the ***editorParams*** with the ***multiselect*** option

```js
{title:"Example", field:"example", editor:"select", editorParams:{multiselect:true}},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I have some questions let me know once u available to reply

Comment: The gender column is not multiselect .single value only selected at a time.I use ctrl+value its not working

Comment: The built in editor supports multiselect, you just need to enable it in the editorParams. The documentation explains all the features

Comment: s document explains all the features.But there no demo for multi select in the documentation

Comment: the documentation explains how to use the features and includes the code for setting up a multiselect editor, but it is not possible to include examples of every configuration for each editor. I will update the answer above with the setup code for multiselect

Comment: ok. I have tabulator version 4.1 .That version only implemented in my all pages..If I moved to version4.7 anything will affect? because multiselect available only in version4.7

Comment: You should be fine, it depends on the features you use. if you checkout the [Upgrade Guide](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/upgrade) for each release it will tell you if you need to change anything